# how can i make .net5 C#9 default targeted framework VS2019

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, c#-9.0

I have enabled preview feature in environment options and installed the sdk. In order for me to use c#9 i have to edit the `<TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>`or use the option so that whenever making a new project i get addional options that lets me change the targeted framework to .net 5.

Is there any way to just set .net 5 as the default targeted framework?

Comment: update your Visual Studio to the latest version.  It's no longer in preview.  It released last week.

Answer (score 3):

It won't default it but it will prompt you to select the framework you want. Go to Tools/Options... and select Environment/Preview Features and check for Show all .NET Core templates.

[image: Preview Features]

Then when you select e.g. your Console template, you can choose the version:

[image]